# Weird looking Google Earth

Tags: 11.04, google-earth

I just installed 64-bit Google Earth from `.deb` file downloaded from the official site. Now when I open Google Earth it looks all weird. Here's a screenshot:
[image: Google Earth].

How to get it right?

Comment: This worked for me:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/70167/google-earth-font-issue-on-installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install ttf-mscorefonts-installer, then logout and in again - see e.g. http://ubuntuguide.net/install-google-earth-and-fix-ugly-fonts-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty (found by searching for "googleearth natty fonts").